# zc702 not BOOTing up my yocto created build

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

Any possible solution in this regard should be appreciated, I have yocto gatesgarth version running on Linux 20.04, have compiled my build successfully with no error messages  but while trying to boot it up on board it does not blink blue led(not loading my build image). have tried by keeping all files in Boot partition and rootfs in root partition but it doesn't even boot (blinked blue LED )
`boot.bin                                                               u-boot.elf boot.bin-zc702-zynq7                                                   u-boot.img boot.bin-zc702-zynq7-v2020.01-xilinx-v2020.2+gitAUTOINC+bb4660c33a-r0  u-boot-xlnx-initial-env boot.scr                                                               u-boot-xlnx-initial-env-zc702-zynq7 core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7-20210623025329.qemuboot.conf            u-boot-xlnx-initial-env-zc702-zynq7-v2020.01-xilinx-v2020.2+gitAUTOINC+bb4660c33a-r0 core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7-20210623025329.rootfs.cpio              u-boot-zc702-zynq7.elf core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7-20210623025329.rootfs.cpio.gz.u-boot    u-boot-zc702-zynq7.img core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7-20210623025329.rootfs.manifest          u-boot-zc702-zynq7-v2020.01-xilinx-v2020.2+gitAUTOINC+bb4660c33a-r0.elf core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7-20210623025329.rootfs.tar.gz            u-boot-zc702-zynq7-v2020.01-xilinx-v2020.2+gitAUTOINC+bb4660c33a-r0.img core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7-20210623025329.testdata.json            u-boot-zynq-scr--1.0-r0.scr core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7.cpio                                    uEnv.txt core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7.cpio.gz.u-boot                          uImage core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7.manifest                                uImage--5.4+git0+62ea514294-r0-zc702-zynq7-20210622034511.bin core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7.qemuboot.conf                           uImage-zc702-zynq7.bin core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7.tar.gz                                  zImage core-image-minimal-zc702-zynq7.testdata.json                           zImage--5.4+git0+62ea514294-r0-zc702-zynq7-20210622034511.bin modules--5.4+git0+62ea514294-r0-zc702-zynq7-20210622034511.tgz         zImage-zc702-zynq7.bin modules-zc702-zynq7.tgz                                                zynq-zc702--5.4+git0+62ea514294-r0-zc702-zynq7-20210622034511.dtb pxeboot                                                                zynq-zc702.dtb pxelinux.cfg                                                           zynq-zc702-zc702-zynq7.dtb`

i have tried with putty but it do not even display any single character on screen.
IS MY BOOT.BIN HAVE BIT FILE IN IT ? how i can confirm that

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine now. i just have made my BOOT.bin with petalinux and uses my yocto build rootfs as ROOT this is working fine on my board.